# how to automate mesos master/slave intallation in a cluster

Tags: ansible, mesos

I need to install one mesos master and three mesos agents. I have done this before and it was successful. I am looking for automatic script or anisble playbook script which can install or setup a mesos cluster if i provide the master and agent ip address as a parameter.

please let me know if anyone has a similar script to do this or guide me how can I achieve the same.

Comment: I recommend that you check out [Mantl](https://github.com/CiscoCloud/mantl) as it has code for this. Also [PanteraS](https://github.com/eBayClassifiedsGroup/PanteraS).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of Mesos roles on galaxy: https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles?page=1&page_size=10&autocomplete=mesos - surely one of them should be able to do what you need...